# How do you store data values into an array from user input in a dialog box?

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class quiz
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String name, allname, loopname;
    int names, allnames, op, loopsname;
    int arValues[];

    name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter how many friends you have:");
    names = Integer.parseInt(name);
    arValues = new int[name-1];

**for(names = 0; names == names; names++)
{
  loopname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "enter your friend's names);
  loopsname = Integer.parseInt(loopsname);
  arValues[names] = loopsname;
}**

allname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the number of which friends name in which you want to see");
allnames = Integer.parseInt(allname);
op = arValues[allnames];

}

 public static void finish()
{
  System.exit(0);
}
}
```

The code compiles, but when it is ran it has multiple run-time errors, including being out of bounds. need help figuring it out

**Error Message:**

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 at quiz.main(quiz.java:28) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:27‌​2)
```

Comment: Could you copy paste the exact error message?

Comment: Why is your loop condition `values == values`? What do you think it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the for loop, the condition `names == names` is always true. What you should do is use a temporary variable, let's say `i`, like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < names; i++) {
    loopname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter value for array:");
    loopsnames = Integer.parseInt(loopsnames);
    arValues[i] = loopsnames;
}
```

Each iteration of the loop now checks `i` to see if it is less than `names`, and if that is true, increments it and runs the code inside the loop. This ensures that the loop will run exactly `values` times. The other place that was causing an error was the line:

```
arValues = new int[names-1];
```

You should have done:

```
arValues = new int[names];
```

Since you want to keep exactly `names` elements.
Here is a complete and working version of your code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class  quiz {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name, allname, loopname;
        int names, allnames, op, loopsname;
        int arValues[];

        name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter how many friends names you would like ot enter");
        names = Integer.parseInt(name);
        arValues = new int[value];

        for (int i = 0; i < names; i++) {
            loopname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your friend's name");
            loopnames = Integer.parseInt(loopname);
            arValues[i] = loopnames;
        }

        allname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the number of which friend you want to see");
        allnames = Integer.parseInt(allname);
        op = arValues[allnames];
    }

    public static void finish() {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Assigning the return value (void) of `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( )` is completely useless; just call the function without assigning the return value to a variable. This is because `showMessageDialog` is just for displaying a message to the user, not taking input.

Comment: BTW, if you want to make it less Google-able you might consider changing the title.